# Robocopy - Compare modified dates of files?

Tags: vbscript, last-modified, robocopy

I've been trying to create this script that basically mirrors two sets of folders and it's content (including subfolders), but only copy files that are newer than the ones that already exist. I tried doing this by writing a vbscript, but it turns out that I manualle need to scan each subfolder and then it's content. And then that subfolder's content as well and so on and so forth.

So I'm wondering if anyone knows if this can be done with Robocopy?

Comment: I'm just throwing this in for extra info but somewhat on topic. I recently had to do this via ftp and this program do a quick job of it http://www.scriptftp.com/ . Sometimes better to not reinvent the wheel. I'm not affiliated in anyway, and I realize you are talking local paths, but thought you might later need to go server to server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ROBOCOPY %SOURCE_DIR% %TARGET_DIR% * /MIR`

### CORRECTION

`ROBOCOPY %SOURCE_DIR% %TARGET_DIR% * /MIR /XO`

Comment: -1 The OP specifically said "but only copy files that are newer than the ones that already exist". /MIR does not do that - it mirrors the source into the target, overwriting target files even if newer. If the OP ran this, it would trash any destination files that were newer.

Comment: @Rob Levine I forgot the /XO. Thanks for the comment, but a little time to correct my answer before you downvote would be nice.

Comment: This kinda works. But you see, it's setup like this:
If user is member of group1, copy \\server\folder to c:\dest\
If user is member of group2, copy \\server\folder2 to c:\dest\

Guess what happens when the user is member of both? :) This is my problem.

Comment: Ok, so I just tried to remove the /MIR switch. And this results in kinda the behaviour I want. If the user is member of both groups, he gets both contents. BUT, if I remove a file or folder from the source path and then run the script, it doesn't remove it from the local path, naturally. So, perhaps I need to combine this with a separate vbscript function that basically compares files and folders and deletes accordingly?

Comment: @Kenny Bones You're getting into a pretty tricky situation here. What if \\Server\Folder and \\Server\Folder2 have folders with the same name?

Comment: Yeah, there are no duplicate folder names :) I know this for sure cause the folders are set up not to collide in any way.

Answer (score 2):

In short - yes - this is nice and simple with RoboCopy. By default it only copies changed files anyway, and won't bother copying unchanged files. You just need to add one argument to get it to exclude files where the destination exists and is newer.

The syntax of RoboCopy is a little bit quirky, so you may want to read more from [here](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html).

You probably want something like this:

```
RoboCopy.exe %sourceDir% %targetDir%\ *.* /xo
```

`%sourceDir%` - your source directory

`%targetDir%` - your target directory

`*.*` - the files in the source directory to copy

`/xo` - exclude file if the destination already exists and is newer.

**[Edit in response to comment]**

If you are saying you want to remove files from the destination directory that no longer exist in the source directory, then I believe the switch `/purge` does this.

Comment: Hi, this does work :)
However, say if the source folder has files and folders that I just removed because I don't need them anymore? I just tried that and that file or folder is still in the destination folder. 

I should use some sort of mirror function I think. Just not wiping out the entire destination in the process. I could write a vbscript that does this as well though. Just checks the files and folders to see if the content match. And then use robocopy to copy newer files.

Comment: Are you saying you want to remove files from the destination if they no longer exist in the source?

Comment: You either need to add /E to cover subdirectories, or use /MIR which is equivalent to /E /PURGE

Comment: i would also include /FFT - especially if you copy files between a windows and a linux file system. or it will not get the correct file dates and will copy everything over and over again.