# Using powershell to copy new and updated files

Tags: powershell, delta

I am a complete novice when it comes to powershell, but I have been given a script that I need to improve so that we can move updated or new files from one server to another. I've managed to get to grips with the current script but am struggling to find the right cmdlets and paramters to achieve the desired behaviour.

The script I have is successful at detecting changed files and moving them to a location ready for transfer to another server, but it doesn't detect any new files.

Can anyone give me some guidance as to how I would be able to achieve both behaviours?

```
$CurrentLocation = "C:\current"
$PreviousLocation = "C:\prev"
$DeltaLocation = "C:\delta"

$source = @{}

#
# Get the Current Location file information
#
Get-ChildItem -recurse $CurrentLocation | Foreach-Object {
    if ($_.PSIsContainer) { return }
    $source.Add($_.FullName.Replace($CurrentLocation, ""), $_.LastWriteTime.ToString())
}
Write-Host "Content of Source"
$source

$changesDelta = @{}
$changesPrevious = @{}

#
# Get the Previous Directory contents and compare the dates against the Current Directory contents 
#
Get-ChildItem -recurse $PreviousLocation | Foreach-Object {
    if ($_.PSIsContainer) { return }
    $File = $_.FullName.Replace($PreviousLocation, "")
    if ($source.ContainsKey($File)) {
        if ($source.Get_Item($File) -ne $_.LastWriteTime.ToString()) {
            $changesDelta.Add($CurrentLocation+$File, $DeltaLocation+$File)
            $changesPrevious.Add($CurrentLocation+$File, $PreviousLocation+$File)
        }
    }
}
Write-Host "Content of changesDelta:"
$changesDelta
Write-Host "Content of changesPrevious:"
$changesPrevious

#
# Copy the files into a temporary directory
#
foreach ($key in $changesDelta.Keys) {
    New-Item -ItemType File -Path $changesDelta.Get_Item($key) -Force
    Copy-Item $key $changesDelta.Get_Item($key) -Force
}
Write-Host $changesDelta.Count "Files copied to" $DeltaLocation

#
# Copy the files into the Previous Location to match the Current Location
#
foreach ($key in $changesPrevious.Keys) {
    Copy-Item $key $changesDelta.Get_Item($key) -Force
}
```

Comment: If this is a script file, I'd be explicit when you are calling known cmdlet parameters, such as `Get-ChildItem -Path` or `-LiteralPath` if you don't want wildcards to get through.  Additionally, in your `If ($_` clause, you should use `Continue` instead of `Return` so it still processes the rest of the pipeline.  Just some observations as I don't understand your ultimate goal.  Changed compared to what?

Comment: Apologies, I didn't think i'd been clear enough. We want to compare the state of files after a period of time. This will be used to move new update files or changed update files. So the script needs to detect new files in the 'current directory' when compared to the 'previous directory' as well as any changes to files in 'current' compared to 'previous', these files then need to be copied to the temporary 'delta' directory. Is that a bit clearer?

Comment: So are the files duplicated in some way that you're doing a comparison to?  Do you look at just updated files, or new files as well?

Comment: We are comparing the files in 'current' to the files in 'previous'. We want to know when there is a new file in 'current' by the comparison showing that there is no corresponding file in 'previous'. We then also want to look at the last write time timestamp to determine if a file has changed. Once the script has fun, the final task will be to copy the new and update files into both a 'delta' directory and into the 'previous' directory so that 'previous' and 'current' will then match.

Comment: Now I understand your problem.  Give me a few and I'll post an answer for ya.

Comment: Honestly, I would not use PowerShell for this.  I would use [robocopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871931/robocopy-compare-modified-dates-of-files) or, if you really, *really* need to track file moves for some reason, just put the files into version control and manage it that way.  Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplified approach to your needs.  One thing to note is that some of the constructs I've used require `PSv3`+.  This does **not** copy directory structure, just the files.  Additionally, it compares the basenames (ignoring extensions) which may or may not do what you want.  It can be expanded to include extensions by using `.Name` instead of `.BaseName`

```
#requires -Version 3

$CurrentLocation  = 'C:\current'
$PreviousLocation = 'C:\prev'
$DeltaLocation    = 'C:\delta'

$Current  = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $CurrentLocation -Recurse -File
$Previous = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $PreviousLocation -Recurse -File

ForEach ($File in $Current)
{
    If ($File.BaseName -in $Previous.BaseName)
    {
        If ($File.LastWriteTime -gt ($Previous | Where-Object { $_.BaseName -eq $File.BaseName }).LastWriteTime)
        {
            Write-Output "File has been updated: $($File.FullName)"
            Copy-Item -LiteralPath $File.FullName -Destination $DeltaLocation
        }
    }
    Else
    {
        Write-Output "New file detected: $($File.FullName)"
        Copy-Item -LiteralPath $File.FullName -Destination $DeltaLocation
    }
}

Copy-Item -Path "$DeltaLocation\*" -Destination $PreviousLocation -Force
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It seems to do the job, however I am now hitting an issue whereby I get the following output:

"Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.DateTime"."

It's something to do with the If ($File.LastWriteTime... line and I have absolutely no idea why it can't do the conversion.

Comment: @matt_isbell that probably means you're running into duplicate base names and it's trying to do a group comparison

Comment: Hmm, does the base name include the file extension? The files we are trying to move are AV update files so there may well be same filenames but different extensions.

Comment: @matt_isbell Correct.  `.Name` includes extensions like I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Ah yes! That will teach me to read the whole thing!!! Sorry. Thanks for all your help.